# how to specify csv file name for downloading in window.location.href

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, encoding

I am exporting data using javascript to csv. **for some reason i am not allowed to use the traditional 
`<a download="filename.csv" /a>`** to set the file name.

I have the following line of code:

```
window.location.href = "data:text/csv;base64," + csvdata
```

Where and how can i insert and specify  the file name and extension to make it work?

Comment: FYI, i am using Angular. with ng-click to trigger a function. due to some aspect, i would not and cannot create a <a>  tag in place. thus would there be another way to just specify in window.location.href to specify the filename?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not possible that way, try to emulate the `<a href=..` with a click on it like this:

```js
        var csvdata = "Hello World"; //  only for test
        var byteNumbers = new Uint8Array(csvdata.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < csvdata.length; i++)
  {
   byteNumbers[i] = csvdata.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  var blob = new Blob([byteNumbers], {type: "text/csv"});
   
        // Construct the uri
  var uri = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  // Construct the <a> element
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = 'myfile.csv';
  link.href = uri;

  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();

  // Cleanup the DOM
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  delete link;
```

Comment: is it absolutely not possible other way? php can specify headers, and i am wondering if there's any javascript equivalent there.

Comment: There are. But not with the `window.location` property. This gives a new URL to the browser, which expects the headers to come from that URL serverside - nature of headers.